# Caching best practice using .net core and APIM

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-api-management

I am new to APIM caching. I am building a .net core webapi project (micro Service) which has GET endpoint for example "GetProduct(QueryPara parameters) (see below)". I would like to implement caching.

Note: My web api (service) is called via APIM.

My requirement is If Get parameter remain the same return data from cache( 2 mins). If input parameters(QueryPara) changes return data from DB.

1. Do I need to implement caching at .net/server level or APIM Level?
2. If at .net core level I can implement caching using https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-response-caching/ such as [ResponseCache(Duration = 120, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
3. My understanding is I don't need cache at .net application/service level. Only need to implement cache policy at APIM is good enough to implement caching? just configure cache-lookup and cache-store (see

Note: My response is less then 2 MB.

```
public QueryPara {
public string Page {get;set;}
public string Limit {get;set;}
public string PurchasedDate {get;set;}
}
```

APIM Cache Policy

```
<cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" must-revalidate="true" allow-private-response-caching="true" caching-type="internal" >
<vary-by-query-parameter>productCode</vary-by-query-parameter>
<vary-by-query-parameter>pageNo</vary-by-query-parameter>
<vary-by-query-parameter>limit</vary-by-query-parameter>
</cache-lookup>
</inbound>
<backend>
<base/>
</backend>
<outbound>
<cache-store duration="2400" />
<base/>
```

If you can share some example that would be excellent.

Thanks

Comment: I think caching on APIM level will be enough. It's easy and no code changes

Comment: As said, you could set caching on `APIM` level much easier. You could have a look at this [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#StoreToCacheByKey)

Comment: Please find a working example here: https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.developer.azure-api.net/api-details#api=evaluation&operation=62ce45471cb8cbe3725b55ed

Comment: Thank Markus. really appreciate it

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, while testing the above url, I am setting "Cache-Control: private, max-age=120" but in response I am getting "cache-control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache pragma: no-cache"

I would like APIM to honour backend api. So, In my API(.net core). I have done appsetting see below. 
Now APIM should response as cache-control: private. AM I right?


 "CacheProfiles": {
    "PrivateCache": {
      "Duration": 120,
      "Location": "Client"
    }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As suggested by @Markus Meyer, Here is the complete policies of Cached APIM and the [documentation](https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.developer.azure-api.net/api-details#api=evaluation&operation=62ce45471cb8cbe3725b55ed) with the example of Cached APIM.*

```
  <policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" must-revalidate="true" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="internal">
                <vary-by-header>userAuthorizationToken</vary-by-header>
                <vary-by-query-parameter>productCode</vary-by-query-parameter>
                <vary-by-query-parameter>pageNo</vary-by-query-parameter>
                <vary-by-query-parameter>limit</vary-by-query-parameter>
            </cache-lookup>
            <rewrite-uri template="/private/product" />
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <forward-request timeout="10" />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
            <cache-store duration="2400" />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Comment: one question why we need rewrite-uri and forward-request?